# How to test horizontal scroll in a Nuxt app using Jest?

Tags: vue.js, scroll, jestjs, horizontal-scrolling

Im working on a proyect that use an horizontal scroll in the home page, my task is to create a test to verify that the horizontal scroll is working fine. This is the page/component

```
<div>
    <p>
      Home: Placeholder text until we replace this with some content
      horizontally scrollable.
    </p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import {
  scrollHorizontally,
  enableCustomScrolling,
  disableCustomScrolling
} from '~/helpers';

export default {
  beforeMount() {
    enableCustomScrolling(scrollHorizontally);
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    disableCustomScrolling(scrollHorizontally);
  }
};
</script>
```

The functions that we are currently using are called from the helper

helpers.js

```
import { SCROLL_SPEED } from '~/constants';

export function scrollHorizontally(event) {
  event = window.event || event;
  const delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, event.wheelDelta || -event.detail));
  document.documentElement.scrollLeft -= delta * SCROLL_SPEED;
  document.body.scrollLeft -= delta * SCROLL_SPEED;
  event.preventDefault();
}

export function enableCustomScrolling(onScroll) {
  if (window.addEventListener) {
    // IE9, Chrome, Safari, Opera
    window.addEventListener('mousewheel', onScroll);
    // Firefox
    window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', onScroll);
  } else {
    // IE 6/7/8
    window.attachEvent('onmousewheel', onScroll);
  }
}

export function disableCustomScrolling(onScroll) {
  if (window.removeEventListener) {
    // IE9, Chrome, Safari, Opera
    window.removeEventListener('mousewheel', onScroll);
    // Firefox
    window.removeEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', onScroll);
  } else {
    // IE 6/7/8
    window.detachEvent('onmousewheel', onScroll);
  }
}
```

Any idea of how to test that?

Comment: The test will likely depend on the implementation of  `scrollHorizontally`, `enableCustomScrolling` and `disableCustomScrolling `. Can you show that?

Comment: Oh! of course, sorry. Here is the helper.